# A basic question on commutative finite local rings

Tags: local-rings

Let $R$ be a commutative finite local ring of order $p^n$ ($p$ is a prime and $1\in R$). I'm struggling with the following two basic questions:

(a) Is it true that $x^n=0$ for every non-unit $x\in R$ ?

(b) Is there exists a nilpotent element $x\in R$ such that $x^{n-1}\neq0$ ?

My guess is that the answer to both questions is false, but unfortunately I can not find any appropriate counterexamples.

Comment: Have you investigated the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$? What are the answers to your questions for this $R$?

Comment: It seem to be true in this case: If $\bar{x}\in \mathbb{Z}/(p^n)$ is non-unit, then $p\mid x$, so $\bar{x}^n=\bar{0}$. conversely, $\bar{p}^{n-1}\neq \bar{0}$ in $ \mathbb{Z}/(p^n)$

Comment: Very well. How does the general case differ from this special case?

Comment: We can not say that $p\mid x$? does every non-unit of $R$ is of the form $py$ for some $y\in R$? it is not clear to me why $p^n=0$ in $R$

Comment: Thanks @kabenyuk. I will be appreciate if you can explain it to me. I have only basic knowledge in ring theory.

Comment: Another good example of a local ring of $q=p^n$ elements is the field $F_q$.

Comment: Since $R^{+}$ is abelian group of order $p^n$ we deduce that $p^n\bar{p}=0$, so $\bar{p}$ is non-unit. In addition, $\bar{p}R$ is an ideal in $R$. Is it maximal? If it does, then indeed every non-unit element is of the form $\bar{p}y$. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer your first question.

In any commutative local ring $R$ of order $p^n$ it is true that $x^n$=0
for every non-unit $x\in R$.

Let $R^* $ be the set of units of $R$ and
$M$ be the maximal ideal of $R$.
Then $|M|=p^k$ for some non-negative integer $k<n$
and $|R^*|=p^n-p^k=p^k(p^{n-k}-1)\geq p-1$.

Let $x\in M$. Let us prove that $x^n=0$.

Note first that if $x,\ldots,x^s$ are all nonzero, then
$$
a_1x+\ldots+a_sx^s=0,\ a_i\in R^*\cup\{0\}\ \Rightarrow\ a_1=\ldots=a_s=0.
$$
Indeed, if $a_1x+\ldots+a_sx^s=0$ and $a_1\neq0$, then
$x(a_1+\ldots+a_sx^{s-1})=0\ \Rightarrow\ x=0$.

It follows that elements of the form
$a_1x+\ldots+a_sx^s=0,\ a_i\in R^*\cup\{0\}$ are at least $p^s$.

So $s<n$, and then $x^n=0$.

Comment: thanks @kabenyuk. You claim that the set of elements $$\{a_1x+\ldots+a_sx^s:a_i\in R^{\ast}\cup\{0\}\}$$ are distinct? why?

Comment: what about the second question?

Comment: It is sufficient that the set of elements
$$
a_1x+\ldots+a_sx^s,\ a_i=t_i\cdot1,\ 0\leq t_i<p,
$$
are distinct. The answer to the second question is negative. For example, let $R=F_q$ be a field of order $q=p^n$, $n>1$. It has no nilpotent elements with the property $x^{n-1}\neq0$.

Comment: thanks @kabenyk.